# codeigniter not going to folder

Tags: php, codeigniter, plesk

I created a new website with codeigniter on local host and it working successfuly but I upload it to plesk host and create a web.config for it

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
    <asp scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true"/>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?url={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite> 
</system.webServer>
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
</system.web>
```

my projrct work successfully but when I'm go to internal folders I get this error

```
404 Page Not Found

The page you requested was not found.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not really sure on this.

1. Do the same web config on your local machine and check this out.
2. Make sure you have the permission 0755 set for all the inner folders recursively. For a test may be you can give full permission as 0777 to all the inner folders and check. Make sure you revert back to the necessary permission.